# Use Sitecore service Client Get Item or Item Id based on the Search term using fields

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-api, item-web-api, itemservice

Is there any way to get Item or Item id using Sitecore Service client based on the fields in the master database.

**Search term:**

```
http://{host}/sitecore/api/ssc/item/search?term=12345&includeStandardTemplateFields=False&fields=Email
```

**Result JSON:**

```
"TotalCount": 1,
  "TotalPage": 1,
  "Links": [],
  "Results": [
    {
      "Email": "emailid"
    }
```

But I need the Item Id or Item itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is feasible to get the item id from the return result. You just need to add the `itemid`in the field projection. Please see below the updated Rest API

```
http://{host}/sitecore/api/ssc/item/search?term=12345&includeStandardTemplateFields=False&fields=Email,itemid
```

I did a small test with the home item and the result are shown below (which returns the item id from where it got the result)

**REST API**

```
http://{domain}c/sitecore/api/ssc/item/search?term=home&includeStandardTemplateFields=False&fields=itemid,title
```

**Response**

```
{
  "TotalCount": 2,
  "TotalPage": 1,
  "Links": [],
  "Results": [
    {
      "ItemID": "8e18ac80-0084-4859-8df4-d8a2fffa5f3b"
    },
    {
      "ItemID": "110d559f-dea5-42ea-9c1c-8a5df7e70ef9",
      "Title": "Sitecore Experience Platform"
    }
  ]
}
```

More information can be obtained from the [Sitecore Documentation - The ItemService](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/en/the-itemservice.html).

In the section **ItemModel return values**, it shows what are the different values that it returns. You just need to specify them in the field projection.

Comment: Hishaam Namooya , okay i will try.

Comment: Thanks Hishaam Namooya, its working.